# SQL AGGREGATE FUNCTION WITH SUM(CASE

Tags: t-sql, sum, case, aggregate

I understand that i cannot perform a subquery in an aggregate function. How can i get around this issue. I need to be able to figure out the current fiscal period from another table and pass it to my query. I am trying to calculate month to date numbers. Any ideas appreciated.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE
             WHEN CRMBNB_DATE_1.AccountingFiscalPeriod = 
                            /*Problem subquery*/
                            (SELECT AccountingFiscalPeriod
                            FROM   crmbnb_date
                            WHERE  DAY = cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 110) AS DATE))
                  AND ( CRMBNB_DATE_1.FiscalYear = YEAR(DATEADD(mm, -3, GETDATE())) ) THEN BL_Amount
             ELSE 0
           END) AS [MTD Billing]
FROM   CRMBNB_BILLINGS
       INNER JOIN CRMBNB_DATE AS CRMBNB_DATE_1
         ON CRMBNB_BILLINGS.InvoiceDate = CRMBNB_DATE_1.Day
       INNER JOIN CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE AS CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1
         ON CRMBNB_BILLINGS.BL_EmployeeNo = CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1.EmployeeNo
       INNER JOIN CRMBNB_SALESREGION AS CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1
         ON CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1.Employee_Region = CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Region
WHERE  ( CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Area IN ( 'OGS' ) )
--AND (CRMBNB_DATE_1.AccountingFiscalPeriod IN (10)) AND (CRMBNB_DATE_1.FiscalYear IN (2013)) 
--AND (CRMBNB_BILLINGS.BL_ProductLine IN (@PRODUCTLINE))
GROUP  BY CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Area,
          CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Region,
          CRMBNB_DATE_1.AccountingFiscalPeriod,
          CRMBNB_DATE_1.FiscalYear,
          CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.RegionDesc,
          CRMBNB_BILLINGS.BL_ProductLine
```

HERE IS THE ERROR

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Cannot perform an aggregate
>   function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function instead of a "Subquery", for example:

```
    SELECT SUM(CASE
         WHEN CRMBNB_DATE_1.AccountingFiscalPeriod = 
                      **Fn_XXX()** THEN BL_Amount
         ELSE 0
       END) AS [MTD Billing]
 FROM   CRMBNB_BILLINGS
   INNER JOIN CRMBNB_DATE AS CRMBNB_DATE_1
     ON CRMBNB_BILLINGS.InvoiceDate = CRMBNB_DATE_1.Day
   INNER JOIN CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE AS CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1
     ON CRMBNB_BILLINGS.BL_EmployeeNo = CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1.EmployeeNo
   INNER JOIN CRMBNB_SALESREGION AS CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1
     ON CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1.Employee_Region = CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Region
    WHERE  ( CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Area IN ( 'OGS' ) )
  --AND (CRMBNB_DATE_1.AccountingFiscalPeriod IN (10)) AND (CRMBNB_DATE_1.FiscalYear IN (2013)) 
     --AND (CRMBNB_BILLINGS.BL_ProductLine IN (@PRODUCTLINE))
         GROUP  BY CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Area,
      CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Region,
      CRMBNB_DATE_1.AccountingFiscalPeriod,
      CRMBNB_DATE_1.FiscalYear,
      CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.RegionDesc,
      CRMBNB_BILLINGS.BL_ProductLine
```

In your function, you can select, update, do everything you need...

Hope this works...

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Move your select statement down to a join, then sum it:

```
SELECT SUM(temp_result)

FROM SELECT
         WHEN CRMBNB_DATE_1.AccountingFiscalPeriod = 
                      (SELECT AccountingFiscalPeriod
                        FROM   crmbnb_date
                        WHERE  DAY = cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 110) AS DATE))
              AND ( CRMBNB_DATE_1.FiscalYear = YEAR(DATEADD(mm, -3, GETDATE())) ) THEN BL_Amount
         ELSE 0
       END) AS temp_result
   FROM   CRMBNB_BILLINGS
   INNER JOIN CRMBNB_DATE AS CRMBNB_DATE_1
     ON CRMBNB_BILLINGS.InvoiceDate = CRMBNB_DATE_1.Day
   INNER JOIN CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE AS CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1
     ON CRMBNB_BILLINGS.BL_EmployeeNo = CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1.EmployeeNo
   INNER JOIN CRMBNB_SALESREGION AS CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1
     ON CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1.Employee_Region = CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Region
WHERE  ( CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Area IN ( 'OGS' ) )
--AND (CRMBNB_DATE_1.AccountingFiscalPeriod IN (10)) AND (CRMBNB_DATE_1.FiscalYear IN (2013)) 
--AND (CRMBNB_BILLINGS.BL_ProductLine IN (@PRODUCTLINE))
GROUP  BY CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Area,
      CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Region,
      CRMBNB_DATE_1.AccountingFiscalPeriod,
      CRMBNB_DATE_1.FiscalYear,
      CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.RegionDesc,
      CRMBNB_BILLINGS.BL_ProductLine
```

I don't have your schema, so I can't test, but it would be along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Similar concept to Damien's answer: You can also stage your subquery output, and then sum the result.

This answer differs in that the all of the fields necessary to produce your desired grouping are included in the inner query's output, so the final output should be the same.

If you prefer, you can also take everything inside the FROM () block below and insert it into a table variable or temporary table. This would make the final query a fair bit simpler.

```
SELECT SUM(results.[MTD billing])
FROM (

  /* Subquery to produce a staged result set */
  SELECT  CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Area,
          CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Region,
          CRMBNB_DATE_1.AccountingFiscalPeriod,
          CRMBNB_DATE_1.FiscalYear,
          CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.RegionDesc,
          CRMBNB_BILLINGS.BL_ProductLine,
          (CASE
               WHEN CRMBNB_DATE_1.AccountingFiscalPeriod = 
                              /*Problem subquery*/
                              (SELECT AccountingFiscalPeriod
                                FROM   crmbnb_date
                              WHERE  DAY = cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 110) AS DATE))
                    AND ( CRMBNB_DATE_1.FiscalYear = YEAR(DATEADD(mm, -3, GETDATE())) ) THEN BL_Amount
               ELSE 0
             END) AS [MTD Billing]
  FROM   CRMBNB_BILLINGS
         INNER JOIN CRMBNB_DATE AS CRMBNB_DATE_1
           ON CRMBNB_BILLINGS.InvoiceDate = CRMBNB_DATE_1.Day
         INNER JOIN CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE AS CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1
           ON CRMBNB_BILLINGS.BL_EmployeeNo = CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1.EmployeeNo
         INNER JOIN CRMBNB_SALESREGION AS CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1
           ON CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1.Employee_Region = CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Region
  WHERE  ( CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Area IN ( 'OGS' ) )
  /* Staging subquery ends here */

) results
GROUP  BY results.Area,
          results.Region,
          results.AccountingFiscalPeriod,
          results.FiscalYear,
          results.RegionDesc,
          results.BL_ProductLine
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of first storing the results in a table variable before performing your SUM().

This method reduces the nesting of subqueries, but it takes some of the decision-making away from the SQL optimizer. I can't guarantee identical performance with this method.

One advantage of separating it out like this is that your results become re-usable, handy if you're wanting to produce multiple result sets from the same data (e.g if you also wanted to produce averages, or wanted to show different levels of grouping).

```
DECLARE @RESULTS TABLE (
  Area NVARCHAR(MAX),
  Region NVARCHAR(MAX),
  AccountingFiscalPeriod NVARCHAR(MAX),
  FiscalYear NVARCHAR(MAX),
  RegionDesc NVARCHAR(MAX),
  ProductLine NVARCHAR(MAX),
  [MTD Billing] NUMERIC(19,4)
)

INSERT INTO @RESULTS
SELECT  CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Area,
        CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Region,
        CRMBNB_DATE_1.AccountingFiscalPeriod,
        CRMBNB_DATE_1.FiscalYear,
        CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.RegionDesc,
        CRMBNB_BILLINGS.BL_ProductLine,
        (CASE
             WHEN CRMBNB_DATE_1.AccountingFiscalPeriod = 
                            /*Problem subquery*/
                            (SELECT AccountingFiscalPeriod
                              FROM   crmbnb_date
                            WHERE  DAY = cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 110) AS DATE))
                  AND ( CRMBNB_DATE_1.FiscalYear = YEAR(DATEADD(mm, -3, GETDATE())) ) THEN BL_Amount
             ELSE 0
           END) AS [MTD Billing]
FROM   CRMBNB_BILLINGS
       INNER JOIN CRMBNB_DATE AS CRMBNB_DATE_1
         ON CRMBNB_BILLINGS.InvoiceDate = CRMBNB_DATE_1.Day
       INNER JOIN CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE AS CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1
         ON CRMBNB_BILLINGS.BL_EmployeeNo = CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1.EmployeeNo
       INNER JOIN CRMBNB_SALESREGION AS CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1
         ON CRMBNB_EMPLOYEE_1.Employee_Region = CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Region
WHERE  ( CRMBNB_SALESREGION_1.Area IN ( 'OGS' ) )

SELECT SUM([MTD billing])
FROM @RESULTS
GROUP  BY Area,
          Region,
          AccountingFiscalPeriod,
          FiscalYear,
          RegionDesc,
          BL_ProductLine
```